# How to write the condition to know whether the user is already logged in or not?

Tags: android, parse-server

I am using **Parse User** class in android studio. I have done login successfully but I dnt want login screen again if I have already logged in.

Comment: Too long for a single answer, but what many apps (and websites) nowadays use are authentication _tokens_.  When/if your user formally logs in, you return an auth token, with some set expiry date.  Every time the user needs to hit the server, he presents the token, and if valid, is then allowed to proceed with the request.

Comment: Thnx @TimBiegeleisen. It's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sharedpreferences` to save the logged in status.

**LoginPage**

```
 SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(this,MODE_PRIVATE);
 onLoginSuccess(){
    pref.edit().put("loggedin",true).commit();
 }

 onCreate(){
    if(pref.getBoolean("loggedin",false){
       //already logged in
        //go to home page
    }
 }
```